# C warning conflicting types

Tags: c, warnings

my code is

```
void doc(){
          //mycode                
            return;
           }
```

my warning is

```
conflicting types for 'doc'
```

can anybody solve it.

Comment: You probably have one more `doc` defined somewhere, check your includes, the error message should tell you where the conflicting declaration is too.

Answer (score 30):

In C, if you don't have a prototype for a function when you call it, it is assumed to return an `int` and to take an unspecified number of parameters.  Then, when you later define your function as returning `void` and taking no parameters, the compiler sees this as a conflict.

Depending upon the complexity of your code, you can do something as simple as moving the definition of the function before its use, or add the function *declaration* in a header file and include it.

In any case, the net effect should be to make the function prototype available before it is being used.

If you add

```
void doc(void);
```

before the function use, you will have a prototype visible in scope, and your warning will go away.

I think this is the most likely cause for your warning.  You could have an explicit incompatible declaration of `doc` in your code, but we can't tell because you have not posted complete code.

Answer (score 17):

try writing your doc function before your main function in your program file.

Comment: Thanks! Care to explain why is this?

Comment: It represents the forward declaration of the function and is the function's prototype.

Answer (score 5):

u have declared it with some other type/signature and defined with some other type/signature..

like

```
int doc();
void doc()
{ 
}
```

will give u this warning.

Answer (score 3):

That's clearly not your complete code.

However, that error means that there is another declaration for `doc` (perhaps a global variable? something in a header file?) that isn't a `void` function that takes no parameters.

Comment: he also may have used the function before its definition

Answer (score 2):

"doc" is probably already declared with a different type...
you should try to find the previous declaration !

Answer (score 2):

You have either declared `doc` before, or made a call to undeclared `doc` thus forcing the compiler to deduce a probable parameter declaration for `doc` from that call. Now, the definition of `doc` that you quoted is different from that previous declaration (either explicit or deduced by the compiler), which is what is reported as a "conflict".

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have not used doc any where in your code !, 
I think that only gives u trouble!

Answer (score 1):

Declaring the function above the usage solved it for me.

Example:

```
void recordAudio(){  //declaration 

    doStuff();
}


void initialise(){ 

    recordAudio();    // usage
}
```

as you can see above, the usage of `recordAudio()` is above where is is used.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you didn't create any function prototype before calling the function. 
So compiler assumes return type as int by default. But while defining function you have used return type as void, which is conflict to complier assumption. that is why you are getting error **conflicting types for 'doc'**

You can solve it by adding a function prototype before main

```
#include <stdio.h>

void doc();

int main()
{
    doc();
}

void doc()
{
      //mycode                
        return;
}
```