# Implicit declaration of function and conflicting type warning

Tags: c, conflict, implicit-declaration

I am currently writing a program in C. Everything works fine, but I get a couple of warning when trying to calk 'make':

```
src/command.c: In function ‘cmd_create’:
src/command.c:43:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘iterator_init’ [-    Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   iterator_init(&it);
   ^
src/command.c:49:6: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘iterator_destroy’ [-    Wimplicit-function-declaration]
      iterator_destroy(&it);
      ^
src/command.c: At top level:
src/command.c:218:6: warning: conflicting types for ‘iterator_init’ [enabled by default]
 void iterator_init(iterator *it) {
      ^
src/command.c:43:3: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘iterator_init’ was here
   iterator_init(&it);
   ^
src/command.c:245:6: warning: conflicting types for ‘iterator_destroy’ [enabled by     default]
 void iterator_destroy(iterator *it) {
      ^
src/command.c:49:6: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘iterator_destroy’ was here
      iterator_destroy(&it);
      ^
```

My research showed that this usually happens when thefunction is declared after the actual call.

However i have properly put the prototypes the of the function in my header files, so was wondering what else could cause this. Is my makefile maybe not set correctly?

The source of my application located on https://github.com/fish-guts/concurrent

Comment: Please don't post links to code, post the actual code.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431242/c-warning-conflicting-types

Comment: This is basic stuff trying to get a program to compile. just comment out chunks of code until it does. Then start adding bits and read the error messages

Comment: Do you ever include your header file? For best effect, always include the corresponding header on the first line.

Comment: Oli Charleswoth: Should I really paste 500 lines of codes?

Deduclicator, yes, my header files are included. I include my "main.h" in every source files and all the corresponding header files are included in main.h

Answer (score 0):

You using function before it was declared. C language allows implicit declarations (still better not use them), and automatically declares function - but implicit rules are quite strict. Later you defining function, but it's prototype isn't matching with auto-generated one.

Possible solutions are:

- define function before using it
- declare function before using it
- include your "command.h", which contains declaration (this is the best option in that particular case)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But as I stated in my post: I properly put in the prototypes of the functions in the headers.

Comment: If code on github you referred to is correct, command.c does not including command.h, hence command.c translation unit does not have prototypes.

Comment: @Fish-Guts from what I can see in your code that's in the repository you do **not** declare your functions in the headers. In `command.h`, there is only a `void interator_init(iterator *it);`, which seems to be a typo. Destroy is missing. But you should really post code snippets instead of linking to a whole repository. This reduces your chances of getting any help at SO.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I will post more code snippets from now on in my own interest :)